# Finding the index in a material where a raycast hit

Tags: unity, raycasting

I have a gameobject with a mesh collider. The mesh is simply a flat plane.

I raycast to the mesh and I'd like to get the index on the material's basemap where I got a hit.

I assumed `hit.textureCoord` or `hit.textureCoord2` would do the trick, but all I get is either `(0,0)` or `(1,1)` and nothing inbetween.

I triple checked and the collider is definitely a mesh collider, so I can only assume I misunderstood what `textureCoord` does

Comment: You know that texture coordinates are expressed in a 0-1 range, so 0.5 is the middle of the texture? By "index" do you mean pixel coordinate in a texture? If so, just multiply the texture coordinate by the texture resolution and round to an integer.

Comment: This looks related to [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/208564/39518). Did you mean to clarify that question with an edit instead of posting a new question about the same topic?

Comment: @DMGregory problem is I only get either (0,0) or (1,1) and nothing in between. And I didn't mean to clarify that question, I think I might have figured that one out, and I plan on answering that question if it works out, but I'm stuck at this point

Comment: Please work up a [minimal verified example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - folks can't do much to troubleshoot code they haven't seen.  Also: the docs have a [simple example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord2.html) of using `hit.textureCoord2` to paint on has a mesh collider; you might try that with your mesh / Texture2D combo to verify they are in working order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I misunderstood what `hit.textureCoord` does. Since the mesh I was dealing with had only 4 vertices and 2 triangles (a simple plane), it can only return `(0,0)` or `(1,1)`, for each of the two triangles.

In general, `hit.textureCoord` seems to return a vector2 associated with the triangle hit, rather than anything to do with the basemap on the material itself.